# How to remove the brackets at the beginning and the end of lines of csv files? [solved] (differences between writerow and writerows for array)

Tags: python, csv

The csv file is like below:

```
[0,0,0]
[]
[1,1]
[]
[]
```

I tried

```
with open('test.csv','r') as r, open('write.csv', 'w') as w:
    for line in r:
        line = line[1:-2]
        w.write(line + '\n')
```

but it outcomes

```
0,0,0
]
1,1
]
]
```

which should be:

```
0,0,0

1,1
```

That was weird for the empty list line, I have to do `line[1:-3]` to clean the line, but for the non-empty line with `line[1:-2]`

Here was how I wrote data into csv file:

```
list = [[0,0,0],[],[1,1],[],[]]

with open ('test.csv','a') as w:
    w = csv.writer(w, delimiter = '\n')
    w.writerow(list)
    w.close
```

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: `line = line[1:-1]`

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy That won't remove the newline.

Comment: @CaptainMhmdrz_A Thanks, I edited that

Comment: Why are you creating the file with brackets to begin with? Just do `csv.writer(w).writerows(yourlist)`.  (Note `writerows()` is plural when writing multiple rows.)  Also no need for `w.close()` which you forgot the parenthesis to. The with-statement takes care of closing the file.

Comment: You should fix the way you are writing your data.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thanks!!!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah, definitely

Comment: Design issue aside, is the question itself not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list ?

Comment: @AMC To me, the outcome of this post was not about how to write data to csv or how to remove specific character as I thought before, but made me realized where the problem actually was.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rstrip()` and `lstrip()` to remove specific characters from the dns.

```
line = line.lstrip('[').rstrip(']\n ')
```

This removes the `[` at the beginning and the `]` and newline at the end.

Comment: that outcomes `]` as well for a empty list line

Comment: I just tried with `line = '[]\n'` and the result was `''`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the problem is in the writing of the file in the first place. If this list only has a few base types (int, string, etc), you  can use `ast.literal_eval` to build the list again

```
>>> import ast
>>> with open("test.csv") as f:
...     mylist = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f]
... 
>>> mylist
[[0, 0, 0], [], [1, 1], [], [], [0, 0, 0], [], [1, 1], [], []]
```